# python csv how to make jpg into jpeg

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that will take the csv file, that contains all of the images in the file format:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo
A1,B1,C1,D1,AX1.jpg
A2,B2,C2,D2,BX1.jpg
A3,B3,C3,D3,CX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,BX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,CX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,AX1.jpg
```

script:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    column_numbers = 'Echo'
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
            for ky in row[column_numbers] translate from jpg to jpeg
```

So that the csv file will look like this:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo
    A1,B1,C1,D1,AX1.jpeg
    A2,B2,C2,D2,BX1.jpeg
    A3,B3,C3,D3,CX1.jpeg
    A4,B4,C4,D4,BX1.jpeg
    A4,B4,C4,D4,CX1.jpeg
    A4,B4,C4,D4,AX1.jpeg
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do this with a text editor?  The fact that it's a CSV is irrelevant.

Comment: Or, `sed -e s/jpg/jpeg/ < sample.csv`.

Comment: the command line tool also works great, however it only replaces the first line of each row. If i have multiple lines in the row of the csv it will not replace all of them. Thank you  for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "first line of each row"?  Each row is a line, and the sed script will operate on every line.  I tried it before I posted my comment.  Perhaps your data doesn't actually look like what you showed us.

Comment: yes sorry, for the column Echo, the first line is AX1.jpg,AX2.jpg,AX3.jpg. the second line is BX1.jpg,BX2.jpg,BX3.jpg etc etc. Right now it converts to AX1.jpeg,AX2.jpg,AX3.jpg, and then BX1.jpeg,BX2.jpg,BX3.jpg. etc etc.

Comment: Then why didn't you say that in your problem?  All you need is `sed -e s/jpg/jpeg/g < sample.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, the fact that it is a csv does not matter since you are simply looking to do a search and replace on the text file.

As @Tim Roberts commented, this can be done using command line tools (`sed -e s/jpg/jpeg/ < sample.csv`), but let's do it in Python anyway...

Try this runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python
# to set up let's recreate the file
with open("sample.csv",'w') as f:
    f.write("""
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo
A1,B1,C1,D1,AX1.jpg
A2,B2,C2,D2,BX1.jpg
A3,B3,C3,D3,CX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,BX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,CX1.jpg
A4,B4,C4,D4,AX1.jpg
""")

# now read the file into a string
with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    full_text = csv_file.read()
    
# correct the string
new_full_text = full_text.replace(".jpg", ".jpeg")

# overwrite the original file
with open('sample.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(new_full_text)
    
# check the output

desired_output = """
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo
A1,B1,C1,D1,AX1.jpeg
A2,B2,C2,D2,BX1.jpeg
A3,B3,C3,D3,CX1.jpeg
A4,B4,C4,D4,BX1.jpeg
A4,B4,C4,D4,CX1.jpeg
A4,B4,C4,D4,AX1.jpeg
"""
with open('sample.csv') as csv_file:
    check_full_text = csv_file.read()

print(check_full_text == desired_output)

check_full_text
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What if .replace is used for a string. Is there anything I can use for a variable that is an dictionary or a list?

Comment: No, `replace` is a string method.  You would have to enumerate the members of your list or dictionary to get to the strings.  But how would you end up with such a thing by reading a CSV?